# Laravel Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For some reason a user cannot delete a post if it has been liked, it was working before but when I linked posts with likes I have been getting this error, I can't even delete it in Sequel Pro, unless I delete the likes associated with the post first.

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
> update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`eliapi8`.`likes`, CONSTRAINT `likes_post_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
> (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `posts` where
> `id` = 149)

Maybe it's my schema?

**Posts Schema**

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Likes Schema**

```php
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I can like and unlike a post, but a user cannot delete a post that has been liked.

**PostController.php**

```php
public function destroy(Post $post){
    
    $this->authorize('delete', $post);
    $postl =  Post::with('likes')->whereId($post)->delete();

    if ($post->delete()) {
        if($postl){
             return response()->json(['message' => 'deleted']);
        }  
    };

    return response()->json(['error' => 'something went wrong'], 400);
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, it's your schema. The constraint on `likes.post_id` will prevent you from deleting records from the `posts` table.

One solution could be using `onDelete('cascade')` in the `likes` migration file:

```
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This way, when a post is deleted, all related likes will be deleted too.

Or, if you have a relationship from the Post model to the Like model, you can `$post->likes()->delete()` before deleting the post itself.

Comment: it worked, so i can use onDelete if a post has likes.

Comment: I updated the answer on why it wasn't possible to delete records from the `posts` table.

Comment: I also use ondelete with my schema and it cannot delete give me the same error that u got when i use this $user->activities()->delete(); then delete the user and it all data  but when i simply use $user->delete(); it shows the error Please help.

Comment: @Moaiz Ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: How can you "append" ->onDelete('cascade') to an existing model?

Comment: Well, perhaps I phrased it incorrectly, but I'm not starting a new topic. I was asking if the solution above could be simply added to an existing project model and be expect to just start functioning?

Comment: I think you can use `doctrine/dbal` to alter an existing table and add the `onDelete()` constraint to a foreign key. I guess it should work right away, but haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 11):

I've tested with `onDelete('cascade')` but in my case it didn't work. The resource I tried to delete had a model with an `hasMany()`

```
/**
 * Get the departments of the organization
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function org_departments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Department::class);
}
```

So, in the `destroy()` for the controller `OrganizationUserController`, instead of having

```
$organization->delete();
```

I ensured to delete the departments for that organization first and only then the `$organization`,

```
$organization->org_departments()->delete();

$organization->delete();
```

Then it was deleted just fine.

Comment: this worked for me as well. Thanks

Comment: Asante Sana, this just saved my time

Answer (score 3):

Change `on delete` to `cascade`, instead of `restrict`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are in production mode just php artisan migrate:fresh. It will drop all tables

***Note:Record would be deleted from tables***

**Why you Face this problem??**
Actually you cant delete parent table having data in child table .
First you have to delete the child table data only than can you delete the parent table

you have two option to handle this issue.

1)->onDelete('cascade') with your forigner key in migrations

2) if you are in controller first delete $organization->org_departments()->delete(); so all your child would be deleted first than you can delete the parent child $organization->delete();