# From campaign table i want to delete campaign but i can't delete..following error occur

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (demopurpose_fundraising.campaign_product, CONSTRAINT
>   campaign_product_campaign_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id)
>   REFERENCES campaign (id)) (SQL: delete from campaign where id = 60)

campaign table schema :

```
Schema::create('campaign', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('campaign_name');
            $table->float('campaign_goal',8,2);
            $table->string('discription',400);
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->date('start_date');
            $table->date('end_date');
            $table->float('total_fund',8,2);
});
```

campaign_product table schema :

```
Schema::create('campaign_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('campaign_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaign')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('product')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

campaign_id is foreign key in campaign_product delete..

I want to delete campaign ..
How to delete campaign product then campaign ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544109/laravel-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: Its not solve my problem..@Thamaraiselvam

Comment: How are you trying to delete the record? paste some code...

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm/27805553#27805553 Delete campaign_product, then campaign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete it unless you remove those `campaign_id` from `campaign_product` table. Detach products from the `campaign_product` table before you delete a campaign. Example:

```
$campaign = Campaign::query()->findOrFail($id); //find campaign
$campaign->products()->detach($campaign->product); //detach products from `campaign_products` table
$campaign->delete(); //delete the campaign
```

Read more about detaching many-to-many relationship record: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: What is $id? what is the value in $id?

Comment: `$id` is the row id you want to delete. How do you delete a record, by the way?

Comment: I get all detail of that particular campaign which i want to delete in $campaign.. How to fetch id of that campaign..   Undefine $id error occur.......public function destroy(Campaign $campaign)
{
        $campaign = Campaign::query()->findOrFail($id); 
        $campaign->products()->detach($campaign->product); 
        $campaign->delete(); 
        return Redirect::route('campaign.index')->with('campaign deleted successfully.');    }

Comment: Pass `$id` inside `destroy()` method like `destroy($id)`, no need to bind the Campaign model.

Comment: i do what u say .. but now Method products does not exist error occur..

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is you cant delete a model because it still has connection in your database. You want to make a function that first deletes all the relations before deleting the model in question.

Try adding this to you `Campaign` Model.

```
protected static function boot() {
   parent::boot();

   static::deleting(function($campaign) { // before delete() method, call this
       $campaign->products()->delete();
       // do the rest of the cleanup...
   });
}
```

If you follow the process given in the link in the comments you can prevent this issue from happening in the future.