# Laravel message: Integrity constraint violation: 1451

Tags: database, laravel

I am still learning Laravel and run into an issue when I want to remove a record from the database. Most likely I am missing something simple.

I have a tweet migration that looks like this:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

There is also a likes-migration hat looks like this:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete;
        $table->foreignId('tweet_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete;
        $table->boolean('liked');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'tweet_id']);
    });
}
```

When in tinker I say

```
$tweet->delete();
```

it will delete the tweet-record only when it has no likes.
If the tweet has likes, I get the error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation : 1451 Cannot delete or update a parrent row: a foreign key constraint fails...."
```

I think I make a very basic error in teh migration, but I don't know which.

Who can advise?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544109/laravel-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails. Also, which version are you using?laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a model that has a foreign key associated with it you have to cleanup. You want to cascade it, your syntax seems off, i'm not sure if it is an alternative way. Normally you would do it like so.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('tweet_id')
    ->references('id')->on('tweets')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

A newer version of the on delete cascade can be.

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
    ->constrained()
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I assume that I am doing this. With "  $table->foreignId('tweet_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete;" i assume that I am deleting references to a tweet in the Likes-table when I delete the tweet?

Comment: As i told you the syntax seems off, normally all schema calls are methods and not property accesses. i updated it with another example, check the database if it cascades.

Comment: And as i have seen your profile you have 6 questions without accepted answers, just for your info it is a common courtesy to actually accept the answers that have helped you, i don't care what you do with mine, but respect people who are here to help, the least you can do for the community

Comment: Changing "cascadeOnDelete" to "onDelete('cascade')" did the trick. Thanx. I don't understand where I got the cascadeOnDelete! Also I did not get an error message when I ran the original (faulty)migration.

Comment: Probably because you accessed an property, so if it helped you can accept it as an answer. And you can also go back in time and accept the answers that helped you ;) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

`->cascadeOnUpdate()` is a correct helper method (which is a substitute for `->onUpdate('cascade')` as suggested by others) but it looks like you forgot the brackets. If you correct it to the following, it should work:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('tweet_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->boolean('liked');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'tweet_id']);
    });
}
```