# laravel can't delete a row with one to many relation

Tags: laravel

I have one to many relation in my project ( the user has many details ), and when i delete any user row it says

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sehhatys_saudi`.`details`, CONSTRAINT `details_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `users` where `id` = 9)
```

the details table migration

```
Schema::create('details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('check_date', 100);
        $table->string('result_date', 100);
        $table->string('result', 100);
        $table->string('check_center', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

the User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'name_en', 'national_id', 
'birth_date', 'user_password', 'nationality', 'nationality_en', 
'vaccine_type_one', 'vaccine_type_one_en', 'date_one', 
'batch_number_one', 'vaccine_type_two', 'vaccine_type_two_en', 
'date_two', 'batch_number_two', 'report_id', 'qr_url', 'access_token', 
'phone', 'email', 'social', 'social_en', 'weight', 'height', 'mass', 
'blood_pressure', 'blood_sugar', 'waist', 'hypertension', 
'hypertension_en', 'diabetes', 'diabetes_en', 'city', 'city_en', 
'health_center', 'health_center_en'];

    public function details(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Detail');
    }
}
```

the Detail model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Detail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'check_date', 'result_date', 
'result', 'check_center'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

the delete function for the user row

```
public function delete($id)
{
    User::findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect(route('users.all'));
}
```

even when edited the delete function and make it like this

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $user->details()->delete();
    $user->delete();

    return redirect(route('users.all'));
}
```

it returns this error

```
Class "App\Detail" not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544109/laravel-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: no my friend, I edited my post take a look at it

Comment: It should be `->onDelete('cascade')` not `->onCascade('delete')` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: should I migrate after update this line?

Comment: @OsamaAmr Yes you have to migrate.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Did you check whether the changes were properly migrated to the database, as usual when you change the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name space for your Detail Model is `namespace App\Models;` While you are using `App\Detail` in `User.php`.

The relation in User model should be:

```
public function details(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Detail');
}
```

If you are using laravel-8 it should be like:

```
public function details(){
    return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Detail::class);
}
```