# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, schema, database-migration

I'm getting this error, upon running  `php artisan migrate`.

```dart
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists `products`)
```

`create_products_table.php` inside migration

```dart
public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            //  Other attributes here
            
            $table->bigInteger('ctg_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('product_variation_id')->unsigned();  
            $table->bigInteger('sub_ctg_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('vehicle_id')->unsigned();  

            $table->foreign('ctg_id')->references('id')->on('ctgs')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_variation_id')->references('id')->on('product_variations')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('sub_ctg_id')->references('id')->on('sub_ctgs')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('vehicle_id')->references('id')->on('vehicles')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
```

I searched online, got this solution, changed the code accordingly but in vain
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544195/7290043

[image]

For now, I'm just working with the below tables

Comment: Why is `Schema::dropIfExists('products');` in your `up()` method? If the table already exists you should not be recreating it, you should edit it to add/change/remove the specific columns you are working with.

Comment: You can put `Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();` before your `dropIfExists()` call, and re-enable them with `Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();`. But Miken is correct; migrations are meant to be run once; there should be no reason you need to put `Schema::dropIfExists('products');` in the Migration to create the `products` table.

Comment: I'm actually new to laravel. I wanted to add the extra attributes to the table. I added them in migration and run migrate. It was giving an error Base table or view already exists. So I tried to drop it first with `Schema::dropIfExists('products');` and then create a table but is giving the above error. I tried to go through to Laravel docs but it is also not that clear. @miken32 @tim

Comment: The documentation seems quite clear. Don't use the `create()` method to alter an existing table, use the `table()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-tables

Comment: With all the `->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade')` you are saying "if every of the othe tables rows are removed, the product row MUST be removed to", so at the same time other 3 tables are missing the FK. Maybe you want to mantain the product if any related row is deleted so you can set `onDelete("set null")`

Answer (score -2):

You must use `$table->dropForeign()` before deleting the table, Remove the external key to avoid this error.