# I cannot delete data which have many-to-many relationship in laravel 9

Tags: php, many-to-many, laravel-9, laravel-migrations, laravel-controller

I am using PHP 8.2.0, MySQL 8.2.0, and Laravel 9.48.0. This is my database migrations file pivot table (category_menu):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('menu_id')->constrained();
        });
    }
```

This is the CategoryController.php:

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        Storage::delete($category->image);
        $category->menus()->delete(); // many-to-many relationship
        $category->delete();
        return to_route('admin.categories.index');
    }
```

Lastly, this is the MenuController.php:

```
    public function destroy(Menu $menu)
    {
        Storage::delete($menu->image);
        $menu->categories()->delete(); // many-to-many relationship
        $menu->delete();
        return to_route('admin.menus.index');
    }
```

I have tried deleting one of the menu/category, but laravel keeps sending out an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`larareserve`.`category_menu`, CONSTRAINT `category_menu_menu_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_id`) REFERENCES `menus` (`id`))

```
delete `menus` from `menus` inner join `category_menu` on `menus`.`id` = `category_menu`.`menu_id` where `category_menu`.`category_id` = 4
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`larareserve`.`category_menu`, CONSTRAINT `category_menu_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))

```
delete `categories` from `categories` inner join `category_menu` on `categories`.`id` = `category_menu`.`category_id` where `category_menu`.`menu_id` = 7
```

I thought, this error might have to do with the migration's pivot table (category_menu). But, I just don't know how to fix this. I am currently one month old learning the laravel framework and right now, I am working on the tutorial project from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KaBeq9JzrQ). Please help (educate) me anyone. I am sorry for all inconveniences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. Already got the solution from [Laravel Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544109/laravel-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails?rq=1)

so what I did was, in my database migrations file pivot table (category_menu):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('menu_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

CategoryController.php:

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    Storage::delete($category->image);
    $category->menus()->delete(); // many-to-many relationship
    $category->delete();
    return to_route('admin.categories.index');
}
```

MenuController.php:

```
public function destroy(Menu $menu)
{
    Storage::delete($menu->image);
    //$menu->categories()->delete(); // many-to-many relationship
    $menu->delete();
    return to_route('admin.menus.index');
}
```

By adding `->onDelete('cascade')` on the migration file, I can already delete the menu. I also put the syntax only on the menu item in the migration file and commented the line to delete the menu's category method on the MenuController, so that whenever I deleted the menu, the category won't be deleted. If I deleted the category, the menu related to it will also be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another solution for another type of outcome. Let say, whenever I want to delete the menu, only the menu gets deleted. And whenever I want to delete the category, only the category gets deleted.

Migration File (category_menu):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('menu_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

CategoryController.php:

```
public function destroy(Category $category)
{
    Storage::delete($category->image);
    // $category->menus()->delete(); // many-to-many relationship
    $category->delete();
    return to_route('admin.categories.index');
}
```

MenuController.php:

```
public function destroy(Menu $menu)
{
    Storage::delete($menu->image);
    // $menu->categories()->delete(); // many-to-many relationship
    $menu->delete();
    return to_route('admin.menus.index');
}
```